# Android Espresso DrawerActions.open() doesnt work

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-espresso

**I want to open my drawer layout with Espresso and test whether it is open.** But as simple code as:

```
@Test
    fun isDrawerOpening(){
        onView(withId(R.id.drawerLayoutMain))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .check(matches(DrawerMatchers.isClosed()))
            .perform(DrawerActions.open())
            .check(matches(DrawerMatchers.isOpen()))
    }
```

doesn't want to work. `swipeRight()` the same. I get 'Test Failed':

```
[Robolectric] com.zywczas.bestonscreen.views.MainActivityTest.isDrawerOpening: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28

androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is drawer open' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is drawer open
     Got: "DrawerLayout{id=2131230868, res-name=drawerLayoutMain, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=470, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams@22a54b8d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=56.0, child-count=2}"

<Click to see difference>


    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:16)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:36)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:103)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:31)
    at com.zywczas.bestonscreen.views.MainActivityTest.isDrawerOpening(MainActivityTest.kt:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'is drawer open' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is drawer open
     Got: "DrawerLayout{id=2131230868, res-name=drawerLayoutMain, visibility=VISIBLE, width=320, height=470, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams@22a54b8d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=56.0, child-count=2}"

    at androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:17)
    at androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$MatchesViewAssertion.check(ViewAssertions.java:15)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:10)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:11)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$android_os_Handler$handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Handler.$$robo$$android_os_Handler$dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper$IdlingRunnable.run(ShadowPausedLooper.java:308)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.executeOnLooper(ShadowPausedLooper.java:273)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.idle(ShadowPausedLooper.java:85)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalControlledLooper.drainMainThreadUntilIdle(LocalControlledLooper.java:15)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:99)
    ... 19 more
```

**How to make it open by Espresso?** I use Robolectric and Navigation. I want to test my main activity and clicking nav buttons in the drawer. It works when I use the app. But cannot achieve the same with Espresso.

My dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'
testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarMovies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMovies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".views.MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragmentView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navDrawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemIconPadding="20dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">

        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var moviesFragmentsFactory: MoviesFragmentsFactory
    private val navHostFragment by lazy {
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragmentView) as NavHostFragment }
    private val navController by lazy { navHostFragment.navController }
    private val appBarConfiguration by lazy {
        AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.destinationDb, R.id.destinationApi), drawerLayoutMain) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = moviesFragmentsFactory
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navDrawer.setupWithNavController(navController)
        toolbarMovies.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        toolbarMovies.setNavigationOnClickListener(openCloseDrawerNavClick)
    }

    private val openCloseDrawerNavClick = View.OnClickListener {
        if (drawerLayoutMain.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayoutMain.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your test looks good. You should only use `DrawerActions.open` for best practices, unless you have other goals. I think you're probably facing a race condition between `DrawerActions.open()` and `DrawerMatchers.isOpen()`. If that's the case you'll have to wait until the drawers are completely open, you can either use `Thread.sleep()` for quick solution, or `IdlingResource` for elegancy:

```
fun waitUntilOpen(drawerGravity: Int = GravityCompat.START): ViewAction = object : ViewAction {

    private val callback = DrawerOpenCallback()

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> = isAssignableFrom(DrawerLayout::class.java)

    override fun getDescription(): String = "wait for drawer to open"

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        if (!(view as DrawerLayout).isDrawerOpen(drawerGravity)) {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(callback)
            view.addDrawerListener(callback)
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(callback)
            view.removeDrawerListener(callback)
        }
    }
}

private class DrawerOpenCallback : IdlingResource, DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private lateinit var callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback
    private var opened = false

    override fun getName() = "Drawer open callback"

    override fun isIdleNow() = opened

    override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
        this.callback = callback
    }

    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
        opened = true
        callback.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
}
```

Then perform `waitUntilOpen` after `DrawerActions.open()`:

```
@Test fun isDrawerOpening(){
    onView(withId(R.id.drawerLayoutMain))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        .check(matches(DrawerMatchers.isClosed()))
        .perform(DrawerActions.open(), waitUntilOpen())
        .check(matches(DrawerMatchers.isOpen()))
}
```

Comment: I tried 3 things, your solution, `Thread.sleep()`, and `Shadows.shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle()`. Still the same. I will paste my whole class below.

Comment: Strange, does your `DrawerActions.open` really opens the drawer? I wonder if AppBarConfiguration changes its behavior..

Comment: Well, I was thinking the same. I was trying to open it with `navController.navigateUp()`, but I am not sure yet how to reference nav controller from activity. I know how to do it in fragment. Maybe you know Aaron?

Comment: I mean, I am using following, but still the same: `activity.scenario.onActivity { it.navController.navigateUp() }`, also: `activity.scenario.onActivity { it.navController.navigateUp(it.appBarConfiguration) }`

Comment: This doesn't work as well: `activity.scenario.onActivity { it.drawerLayoutMain.open() }`. I must be missing something...

Comment: Well. Apparently it looks like Robolectric cannot open a drawer layout. I haven't found any solution for this.